# Can I restore a PS3 backup to different console without erasing the existing data there?

Tags: ps3

My old fat PS3 is not working normally anymore. For some reason it does not connect well wirelessly to my controllers, does not detect wireless internet and does not detect the ethernet cable. Plus, it got the YLOD twice already so my uncle gave me his slim PS3 very cheap and it has 6 cool games in it.

I was able to make a backup of my fat PS3 using the backup utility since the USB ports seemed to work well.

How can I restore the information of my old fat PS3 onto my slim ps3 without losing either the games already saved into the slim PS3 and my copy-protected Dragon Age save files?

In other words i want to keep the games in the slim PS3 and put everything from my dying  PS3 into the slim one.

I have the fat HDD, the fat PS3 itself and a backup file made from the fat PS3.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Sony's page on the backup utility](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps3/current/settings/backuputility.html), copy protected data can't be restored to another PS3, so it looks like you're out of luck for Dragon Age.

To get the closest to what you want, restore the backup you made onto the slim, and then do as YellowMegaMan suggests to redownload your uncle's games.

Answer (score 1):

After you've transferred the data from your old PS3 to your new one, get your uncle to reenter his PSN account on your new PS3 (ie. as a different user to the one you use).

Then, logged in as your uncle, you will be able to go onto the PSN store and redownload the items your uncle bought. Once they are installed, you can then logout and login back to your own account. The games will still be playable there.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest that you transfer the content into your PC from the old HDD then connect the new HDD to your PC to transfer it back and then install the HDD in your PS3 slim.

Comment: I don't think you can use a PS3 HDD in a computer. Most people say computers wont detect it.

Comment: Yeah it will it's formated in FAT32... Only Mac won't but Windows and Linux will detect that format no problem.

Comment: Ooh cool, will try that then!

Comment: Ooh nevermind, all of my uncle's games seem to be linked to his account. It says i can't play them unless i re activate the license, which takes me to the PSN store to buy the game LOL.

Comment: Mac has no problem with FAT32...

Comment: -1: The PS3 hard disk is NOT formatted FAT32 and cannot be read by a PC

Comment: @YellowMegaMan PS3 HDD are formatted to FAT32

Comment: @Warface: See http://whirlpool.net.au/wiki/ps3_hdd - `Can I take out the PS3's internal HDD, connect it to my PC, and move data on and off the drive?` - *No. The PS3 uses a proprietary file format for its internal HDD, which cannot be read by PCs.*